# Blender camera problems

Tags: camera

I am trying to render my model but the camera kinda shoots into the model. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to bring up the camera view mode it makes my model so large instead of showing the view from the camera.

I'm very new to blender this is my first  project.

Thank you 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to move the camera? Or is it correctly positioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the issue you have is clipping.

You can change that in the Camera a properties:

[image]

Set it to something low this will allow your camera to get closer to your model.